# How to pack Opencv with own program and handle it to new machine

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

i'm using opencv to develop a function of recognizing ocr characters/digits.
i've tried build a dll with my own program with its head like this

```
#ifdef dll_EXPORTS
#define dll_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define dll_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif
    
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/dnn/all_layers.hpp>
    
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <array>
    #include<cmath>
    #include<windows.h>
    #include <fstream>
    
    namespace test
    {
        // This class is exported from the dll.dll
        class dll_API ocr
        {
        public:
            void function1();
            void function2(const string, Net &net);
        };
    }
```

and apparently this dll.h would still require a new opencv environment on new machine, which is incompatible for deploying a program for client, i'm wondering that is there any way of avoiding this and pack all dependency more easily to deploy. Thanks for advice!

Comment: It should be enough to have all the dll in the same directory of the exe. if you are on Windows at least

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to warp all dlls together?Like all in 1 dll. Otherwise it would be such a trouble of changing the version of opencv, i've seen someone else did like this before but not knowing the correct way.

Comment: Indeed copy all items would help in win10, but consider about a software update , it's might not really efficiency, and also a problem for someone who don't use opencv at all.

Comment: I don't see the problem... just create an installer. You can use CPack, is very easy